# Loading TFRecord file in batches

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to load .tfrecord entries in a batch with `tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features(...)`. When I use the following code (similar to the content of `read_and_decode()`) while training the Estimator it works. When I run `load_samples()` it hangs on `eval(session=sess)` when running the script without the Estimator. I guess it is a problem of the pipeline but I am somehow unable to identify the problem. I followed the guide on the [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data#creating_threads_to_prefetch_using_queuerunner_objects) but without any luck.

```
def read_and_decode(sess, cnt):
    def get_reader():
        return tf.TFRecordReader()

    features = tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features(
        file_pattern=os.path.join('.', 'test.tfrecord'),
        batch_size=cnt,
        reader=get_reader,
        features={
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
            'data': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        })
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int64)
    data = tf.decode_raw(features['data'], tf.float32)

    patch = tf.reshape(data, tf.stack( [cnt, 6, 20, 20] ))
    patch.set_shape( [cnt, 6, 20, 20] )

    return label.eval(session=sess), patch.eval(session=sess)

def load_samples():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run([
            tf.local_variables_initializer(),
            tf.global_variables_initializer()
        ])

        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

        try:
            while not coord.should_stop():
                samples = read_and_decode(sess,100)

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as error:
            coord.request_stop(error)
        finally:
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
```

Could you please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: May be its because you are starting the queue_runners and then you are defining the queue (read_and_decode).

Comment: You are indeed right. I find it non-obvious to know what should be the order in which are the pipelines created and run. Thank you. Will you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are starting the queue runners and then you are defining the queue. You need to define the function `read_and_decode()` first and then start the queue runners, that will fix the problem.